# Tensor product of a quotient with $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I don't quite understand the following [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/157026) of the fact that **the quotient of two free abelian groups of the same rank is finite**:

> Let $A\cong B\cong \mathbb{Z}^n$, with $B\subseteq A$.  Then we have the short exact sequence 
>   $$ 0\rightarrow B\rightarrow A\rightarrow A/B\rightarrow 0.$$
>   Tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$ shows $A/B$ has rank $0$, so is torsion.

How does tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$ show $A/B$ have rank $0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because $\Bbb{Q}$ is a flat $\Bbb{Z}$-module, so you get an exact sequence of $\Bbb{Q}$-vector spaces
$$0 \to B \otimes \Bbb{Q} \to A \otimes \Bbb{Q} \to A/B \otimes \Bbb{Q} \to 0$$
which is
$$0 \to \Bbb{Q}^n \to \Bbb{Q}^n \to A/B \otimes \Bbb{Q} \to 0$$
so that
$\dim_{\Bbb Q} (A/B \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} \Bbb{Q})=n-n=0$ .

Comment: @TiWen A vector space of dimension $0$ is…

Comment: Do you mean $\dim_{\Bbb Q} (A/B \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} \Bbb{Q})=\dim_{\Bbb Q} (A \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} \Bbb{Q})-\dim_{\Bbb Q} (B \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} \Bbb{Q})$?

Comment: @TiWen Yes: that's because in vector spaces you have $\dim \ker + \dim \mathrm{range} = \dim \mathrm{domain}$.

Answer (score 0):

Tensoring with $\mathbb{Q} $ (which is flat as a $\mathbb{Z} $-module) yields the exact sequence :

$$0 \to \mathbb{Q}^n \to\mathbb{Q}^n \to A/B \otimes\mathbb{Q} \to 0$$

So $A/B \otimes\mathbb{Q} =0$.