# subgroup of free abelian group with finite index

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $F$ be a free abelian group with rank $n$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $F$. Prove that $H$ is a free abelian group with rank $n$ if and only if $H$ has finte index in $F$.

I know that $H$ is a free abelian group with rank $\leq n$ but i don't know when is the equality holds?

Comment: One direction is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156424